# Resort a Row of textfile

Tags: bash, edit

```
computer0-1   computer0-2   computer0-3
computer0-10  computer0-5   computer0-6
computer0-2   computer0-7   computer0-3
```

These saved in a text file. I want to write a bash script that will check the every line:

- If the line contains `computer0-1` write another `computer0-1` in the beginning of line. For ex:

  ```
  computer 0-1 computer0-10   computer0-5   computer0-1.
  ```
- If the line contain `computer0-7` write another `computer0-7` in the beginning of line.
- If the line contain `computer0-10` write another `computer0-10` in the beginning of line.

I tried to use if and for loop but I don't know how to write them I righ set.

I need to write a script to do this and I'm new in Linux. How can I do this? Is there an easy way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i~/computer0-(1|10|7)$/) print $i, $0}' file | column -t

computer0-1   computer0-1   computer0-2  computer0-3
computer0-10  computer0-10  computer0-5  computer0-6
computer0-7   computer0-2   computer0-7  computer0-3
```

Note that this search is by field order and first match will be printed.  If the priority of the keys is important (in case of -1 and -10 match on the same line always use -1) you can use this

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{pre="computer0-"; p[1]=pre"1 "; p[2]=pre"10"; p[3]=pre"7"}
            {for(i=1;i<4;i++) 
               if($0~p[i]) 
                  {print p[i], $0; 
                   next}
            }' file | column -t
```

Answer (score 2):

With sed :

```
sed -e 's/^.*\b\(computer0-1\)\b/\1\t\0/' -e 's/^.*\b\(computer0-10\)\b/\1\t\0/' -e 's/^.*\b\(computer0-7\)\b/\1\t\0/' <file>
```

It searches for one of the `computer0-1`, `computer0-10`, `computer0-7` in the line and if found places a copy of it at the beginning of the line, followed by a tabulation and the rest of the line.

Detailed explanation :

```
s/<search>/<replace>/ replaces the <search>ed pattern with the <replace> expression
^ matches the start of the line
.* matches everything until the next pattern matches
\b is the word-boundary metacharacter : it matches the start and end of a word of [a-zA-Z_] characters
\(...\) groups a fragment of pattern. We can reference it later.
\1 is a back-reference to the first (and only) group defined earlier
\0 is a back-reference to the whole matched string
```

So what we did is match up to the searched token (i.e. computer0-1) while making sure it's a whole word (computer0-1 shouldn't match computer0-12), then we recreate the matched string by appending it to the matched token.

Test run :

```
$ echo """computer0-1   computer0-2   computer0-3
> computer0-10  computer0-5   computer0-6
> computer0-2   computer0-7   computer0-3""" > input

$ sed -e 's/^.*\b\(computer0-1\)\b/\1\t\0/' -e 's/^.*\b\(computer0-10\)\b/\1\t\0/' -e 's/^.*\b\(computer0-7\)\b/\1\t\0/' input
computer0-1     computer0-1   computer0-2   computer0-3
computer0-10    computer0-10  computer0-5   computer0-6
computer0-7     computer0-2   computer0-7   computer0-3
```

Comment: user specifies "line contains .." so might want to replace the ^ with \s?

Comment: can u explain to me please
what 1 and b and 0 will do